# Local Security Policy blocking non Local Admins from Accessing machine.config

Tags: windows, security

I have a few machines that for some reason won't allow the user (domain user, local user, etc.) the access the machine.config file in the v[.NETversion#]/CONFIG folder. I want to modify the machine.config for this machine, but I get access denied when I try to open the file.

I'm guessing it is a local security policy that is requiring the user be at least a local admin to read/modify this file. Any ideas? It's not group policy, because all users are subject to the same GPOs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably just an NTFS ACL. Have you looked at the permissions assigned to the file yet? The only way that "Security Policy" can affect permission to modify files is through modifying NTFS ACLs.

Comment: I should have specified that.  I did look at that, and even set a particular user with full control.  I still get access denied with that.  The only way to get access to the machine.config is to be a local admin.  NTFS permissions tell me I should be granted access, but it gives me access denied still.

Comment: @Surfer513: How are you accessing the folder remotely? Thru the "\\computer\c$" share?

Comment: It's actually a ClickOnce application that is trying to access it.